# Does Cisco IOS XRv support logging of TCP connection (e.g. built and/or teardown)?

Tags: cisco, logging, cisco-asa, cisco-catalyst

I have a demo of Cisco IOS XRv and I would like to setup logging for connections.

E.g. for ASA "show logging" shows log messages for every TCP connection built or teardown:

```
Jun 11 12:29:31 10.10.10.254 %ASA-6-302013: Built outbound TCP connection 8236065 for outside:x.x.x.x/443 (x.x.x.x/443) to inside:y.y.y.y/58772 (z.z.z.z/58772) 
Jun 11 12:29:36 10.10.10.254 %ASA-6-302014: Teardown TCP connection 8236059 for outside:x.x.x.x/443 to inside:y.y.y.y/49350 duration 0:00:00 bytes 11460 TCP FINs
```

However, if I execute "show logging" on IOS, it only shows information about configuration changes, but no connection traces.

Do I need any additional configuration to enable such connection logging on IOS (to see the connection traces like on ASA)? Or it's not supported at all and I need a separate ASA virtual machine for it?